# How to invoke AWS Chalice function in the test which is not "@app.lambda_function()"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to invoke the AWS Chalice function in the test which is not "@app.lambda_function()"?

```
def test_list():
  logging.debug('Test list poll')
  with Client(app, stage_name='dev') as client:
    result = client.lambda_.invoke('handler', "{'data': 'sample'}")
    logging.debug("result %s", result)
    assert 'pass' == 'pass
```

The above test invokes the lambda function,

```
@app.lambda_function()
def handler(event, context):
    return event
```

If the function is not annotated with "@app.lambda_function()",

the test is not recognizing, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Chalice has attributes to annotate events, like SQS or SNS or DynamoDB. To test-invoke an SQS message for example, try something like this:

```
@app.on_sqs_message(queue="TEST QUEUE", batch_size=1)
def handle_sqs_event(event):
    try:
        for record in event:
            message_body = record.body
            print(record.body)
    except:
        print('Oops!')

def test_sqs():
    _test_sqs_body = {
        "Message": {
            "some_date_value": "2022-03-23",
            "some other field": "some value",
            "status": "complete"
        }
    }

    # (use Chalice's test client to mock up an SQS event and call our handler)
    with Client(app) as client:
        event = client.events.generate_sqs_event(message_bodies=[_test_sqs_body],
             queue_name="TEST_QUEUE")
        response = client.lambda_.invoke('handle_sqs_event', event)
```

This is using Chalice version 1.26.6

Please see the [Chalice Event Sources Tutorial](https://aws.github.io/chalice/tutorials/events.html) for additional information.